# ob_gzhandler mode cause blank page

Tags: php

i have the following code that its working fine with php 5.3

```
function minimize($__OUTPUT_BUUFER__) {
        $__OUTPUT_BUUFER__ = str_replace(array("\r", "\r\n", "\n", "\t", "   "), "", $__OUTPUT_BUUFER__);
        return ob_gzhandler($__OUTPUT_BUUFER__,3);
    }

ob_start("minimize");
```

I have move to php 5.5 and its not working at all. I keep getting blank page.

if i change the ob_gzhandler mode to 1 or 4 or 5 or 6 its working fine
If i use 2 or 3 its not working at all.

Can anyone help me find why its not working with mode 3 because the code is inside a lot of files so if i have to change the mode to something else i have a lot of files to change.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the number "3" you pass to the ob_gkhandler function is the mode. The mode must be a composition of those constants:

```
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_START 
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CONT
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_END
```

The numerical values of those constants has changed across php versions:

```
php 5.3: 
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_START = 1
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CONT = 2
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_END = 4

php 5.4: 
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_START = 1
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CONT = 0
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_END = 8
```

og_gzhandler internal code must have change accordingly.

So, yes, you will have to change your code every where in your script to make it work with php5.5. Prefer using those constants instead of raw numerical values.

Your previous mode was "3" which match the mode:
"PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_START | PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CONT"

So use:

```
        return ob_gzhandler($__OUTPUT_BUUFER__,PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_START | PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CONT);
```

);

Comment: Great answer thanks a lot, i could not find this no matter ho i did search the web